# How to create a winforms FlowLayoutPanel that automatically scales its's childs size?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms app here:

[image]

and when the screen size is exactly the right size all the elements in the FlowLayoutPanel sit perfectly in squares of four, but as soon as the creen size changes these move out of that position, how can I set the FlowLayoutPanel to automatically scale its's children to keep the same layout?

Comment: Unsatisfactory solution (perhaps).  Put a splitter control at the bottom layer of the page, say with horizontal orientation.  Set the proportions so that they are equal.  Then, put two more splitter panels on top of the first one, one in each pane.  Set the orientation opposite to the original panel (i.e., vertical), each with a 50/50% split.  Now you have 4 panes, go to town.  Advantage: your users can move the splits around.  Disadvantage: your users can move the splits around (and move them so that they don't line up)

Comment: "how can I set the FlowLayoutPanel to automatically scale its's children to keep the same layout?"  You probably don't want a FlowLayoutPanel.  Look at the [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead.